# Bind Service to BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-alarms

I have some **Service** class, which registers multiple alarms.

In my **BroadcastReceiver** class, I want the **onReceive**() method to call some method of the **Service** class.

However, I don't see how I can bind them together. I tried to make the **BroadcastReceiver** an inner class, but then I got more errors and couldn't fire the alarm at all.

Thanks

Comment: I found some workaround so it's not relevant anymore. I would still like to know if this can be done. I've tried all sorts of peekSerivce() and using static instance fields, but none works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html life cycle. BroadcastReceiver is created only for handling a message. It means that it's life is very short, ant it is also stateless. So you cannot bind anything to it.

Anyway you can try to start a *service* form `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` method of BroadcastReceiver,
like this:

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, GCMService.class);
        intent2.putExtras(intent);
        context.startService(intent2);
}
```

Then a=the service should handle a broadcast message.

Answer (score 3):

From the http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

> Note: Only activities, services, and content providers can bind to a service - you **cannot** bind to a service from a broadcast receiver.