# HOw to make notificationmanager to work?

Tags: android

When i call

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

I get an error

```
The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type new BroadcastReceiver(){}
```

I'm not sure where I messed up... 
TIA

Comment: where are you calling this statement, in broadcastReceiver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use like

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, calling some methods that involves Context from a BroadcastReceiver isn't safe, as explained for `Context.bindService()` [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383421/bind-service-to-broadcastreceiver).